# VuMeter using LM3915 not working properly

Tags: meter, lm3915

I built a simple Vu Meter on a breadboard using the [LM3915 IC](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General%20IC/lm3914.pdf) following a [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/dotbar-display-driver-hookup-guide) found on the web, all seems to works fine and the final result is something like this:
[image: breadboard scheme]
The only difference is that, instead of connecting the signal PIN on a POT, i've connected it on a 3.5mm audio jack.

The problem is that, with an high-volume audio source, not all the LEDs are actually blinking and, with a low-volume audio source, not even the first LED blink.

I also tried to connecting the REFOUT PIN(the 7th) on a 10K POT but nothing changed.

What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here's the real schematic:

[image: schematic]

Comment: That is not a schematic, but some picture of a circuit *implementation*. As no-one can see what the circuit is supposed to do based on that, it's usual engineering (and problem-solving!!) approach to first draw a schematic of what you've build – to allow us to easily understand what's happening. Schematics are the language of electrical engineers - if you need to ask a question, you should probably speak that language! To make it not so hard to do that, this site has a built-in schematic editor. (Maybe fritzing even allows you to export a proper schematic. I don't know.)

Comment: Could it be something about the signal going negative, perhaps? EDIT: Also, it looks like your schematic doesn't match the fritzing diagram, so I'm going to assume the schematic is what you've actually built. If you actually built the fritzing diagram, I think that one is set up with a 5V reference, whereas its default 1.2V reference is what you want for line audio input. You may also want to add a low-pass filter on the audio input.

Comment: Or just that the signal isn't strong enough to drive the LM3915 to maximum output.

Comment: as @Felthry said the audio signal is 1.2V, it should be the default voltage.

Comment: I also tried to give more than 5V to the circuit but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you actually measure your input signal?

Comment: @icebit. The LM3915 has logarithmic response of 3 dB per LED, so it covers 30 dB of dynamic range. 6 dB is a 2:1 voltage ratio. The LM3914 has a linear response and simply divides the ref input into ten equal steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM3914/15 assumes a DC input, positive polarity, from 0 up to +5V. The audio signal is AC, alternate current. Behavior of LM3914/15 on fast-changing signals is undefined. To make the bar indicator working, you need to rectify your signal using one of methods of "ideal rectifier" or "precision rectifier", something like this:

[image].

Comment: So which one should i use for the LM3915?

Comment: @icebit, what do you mean "which one"? Any rectifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1.2V full scale, you should **ground REF_ADJ** and your R1 should be 1.2/Iout. The 1.2K you show will give you 10mA per LED.

Comment: I just tried it in the breadboard, but sadly it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Measure the DIV_HIGH voltage and see what it reads (should be around 1.2V). Apply a DC voltage from a pot to the input and verify it responds as expected.